# Other than partial sums, is there another method of finding this summation?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$\sum_{i=k}^{n} \frac {1}{i(i+1)}$

Using partial sums I was able to get

$\frac {n}{n+1}$

when k=1, but want to be able to do it more generally, and preferably without listing a sequence of sums. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you MUST use a different method, you could integrate twice

$$ \sum_{i=A}^B x^{i-2} = \frac{x^{B-1} - x^{A-2}}{x-1} $$

and then evaluate at $x=1$...doesn't look easy

Answer (score 6):

The series is telescoping:
$$\frac1{i(i+1)}=\frac1i-\frac1{i+1}$$
Thus the sum reduces to
$$\frac1k-\frac1{n+1}$$